# Is there software to display who lived at a certain time and place?

Tags: gedcom, software-recommendations

Is there genealogy software (as always, preferably for Mac OS X), that reads a GEDCOM file and shows me who lived at a certain point in time at a certain place (and how old this person was)? I am a little tired of checking manually the dates of every John Doe in my database to find those who possibly could be the godfather of the person I am working on.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Family Historian](http://www.family-historian.co.uk/) (PC programme running under [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-mac/) on my MAC) and this has a very powerful query language built in. It allows you to write your own queries that display in table form and the table links back to the individual records.

There is a free 30 day trial of Family Historian available so it may be worth trying it to see if it gives you what you want. There are [several videos on YouTube from Jane Taubman](http://www.youtube.com/user/janetaubman) that run through some of the powerful features of the programme.

Comment: Thank you Colin, I’ll give it a try but leave this question open, e.g. for native alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I use the location feature of gigatrees.com (free site). It doesn't allow you to narrow things down to a certain point in time, but you can quickly narrow your search down to a few individuals and then examine that list for those who fit the timeframe you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Mac Family Tree](http://www.syniumsoftware.com/macfamilytree/) available on the iTunes store for Mac does this under Views->Timeline. It allows you to zoom in and such. What it does not currently do is allow you to filter so if you have a lot of John Does in a particular time range you may get a lot of noise. I have found the developers of Mac Family Tree extremely responsive to bug reports and feature requests so if I a couple of people requested a particular feature I would think it would make it onto their roadmap and they quite actively update the application.

When on PC I was personally a huge fan of [Progency Software's Genelines](https://progenygenealogy.com/products/timeline-charts.aspx) charting software packages that gave you lots of different views of your data and believe it had a nice timeline view as well. Unfortunately it is only available for PC and I have corresponded with them multiple times over the last several years since switching to Mac and they have no intention of porting the software.

Comment: Hi, Christopher, welcome to G&FH.SE.

Answer (score 0):

[Gramps](https://gramps-project.org) (free, open source) can do this, as well as many other reports, queries etc.

Comment: Hi, welcome to genealogy.SE! How exactly does Gramps display this information? What do I need to do? Thanks.